# How to load dynamic content in phantomjs on AWS

Tags: python, selenium, amazon-ec2, phantomjs

I'm trying to parse this page: 
https://www.oslobors.no/markedsaktivitet/#/list/shares/quotelist/ob/all/all/false 
using python 2.7, phantomjs, selenium and bs4 on an AWS EC2 Linux machine. This all works like a charm on both my two machines running Ubuntu and OSX at home. Phantomjs on AWS however seems to be unable to run any scripts and shows not a blank page but a page without any dynamic content:

[Screenshot from selenium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJgr3.png)

```
url = "https://www.oslobors.no/markedsaktivitet/#/list/shares/quotelist/ob/all/all/false"

browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(PHANTOMJS_PATH, service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true', '--ssl-protocol=any'], service_log_path=os.path.devnull)
browser.set_window_size(1280, 1024)
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(10)

soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "lxml")
```

I've tried waiting forever, WebDriverWait, combinations of different ssl-protocols and google all I could to find anything useful but not come across any hint. Does anyone have any clue why this happens?

Comment: If you're using PhantomJS on your home boxes and its working there, I would guess that the PhantomJS version on your EC2 instance is different. That said, I have had similar experiences, and this is why I never use PhantomJS. I have had a lot of success using firefox and chrome on EC2 instances, using Xvfb and the python package pyvirtualdisplay.

Comment: I wouldn't rule out the site blocking AWS

Comment: PhantomJS can be a hassle because it's using a really chopped up WebKit. Checkout NightmareJS if you're just trying to get HTML to parse against, it uses Electron under the hood and defaults to a headless state.